# Do you automatically become a moderator on your own site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, moderators, pro-tem-moderators

I've just been wondering. I know moderators are elected but my question is when you create an area 51 proposal and the site gets launched, Are you made an auto-moderator on the site or do you have to pass through some election or something.

Sorry if this question is a duplicate. If it please point it out to me